# カメラで撮影した画像をリサイズしてアップロードしたい

Tags: javascript, monaca

こんにちは。

monacaとニフティモバイルバックエンドを使ってアプリを作っています。
フォトギャラリーを表示するアプリとそれを管理するアプリを作っています。

別の方が管理するアプリ側の画像をアップロードする部分を書いていたのですが、
数MBあるスマホの画像をそのままアップロードするのでフォトギャラリー側での表示時に
とても時間がかかり実用的ではありません。。

アップロードする前に画像の比率はそのままにリサイズしてアップロードできれば、、と思っています。

その他にも良い案があればご教授いただけると幸いです。
以下がアップロードしているコードの一部です。

よろしくお願い致します。

```
   // 画像選択・カメラ起動
    $scope.showDialog = function(val) {
        if (val == 0) {
            // 画像を選択して取得
            var opt = {
                quality: 50,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            };
        } else {
            // 画像をカメラで撮って取得
            var opt = {
                quality: 50,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            };
        }

        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, opt);
    };

    function onSuccess(data) {
        $scope.img64 = data;
        document.getElementById('new_img').src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
    }

    function onFail() {
        // エラー
    }

    // 追加
    $scope.add = function() {
        if (document.getElementById('new_img').src != "images/no-image.png") {
            var file = toBlob($scope.img64);
            var fileNam = ImgBaseNam + no + ".jpg";

            var ncmbFile = new NCMB.File(fileNam, file);

            ncmbFile.save().then(function() {
                // アップロード成功
                var Obj = NCMB.Object.extend(imgClassNam);
                var obj = new Obj();

                var Today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

                obj.save(null, {
                    success: function(obj) {

                    alert("データを保存しました。");

                    },
                    error: function(obj, error) {
                        alert("データを保存に失敗しました。, error code: " + error.message);
                    }
                });
            }, function(error) {
                // アップロード失敗
                alert(error.message);
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML/JavaScript で画像データを縮小するには、`<canvas>`を利用する方法があります。
Canvas に縮小サイズで描画した後、Canvas 自体を画像データとして取得する感じです。

動くデモ: http://jsbin.com/bojowaseji/1/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" onchange="onInputChanged(event)">
  <hr>オリジナルサイズ:<br>
  <img id="previewLarge">
  <hr>縮小サイズ:<br>
  <img id="previewSmall">
  
  <script>
    function onInputChanged(e) {
      var file = e.target.files && e.target.files[0];
      if (file != null) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = onImageLoad;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
    function onImageLoad(e) {
      var largeData = e.target.result;
      var smallData = makeSmall(largeData);
      previewLarge.src = largeData;
      previewSmall.src = smallData;
    }
    
    // 画像データ(DataURL)を縮小して返す
    function makeSmall(data) {
      // 画像データの縦横サイズを取得する
      var image = document.createElement('img');
      image.src = data;
      var width = image.naturalWidth;
      var height = image.naturalHeight;

      // 縮小する。今回は縦横それぞれ1/2
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = width / 2;
      canvas.height = height / 2;
      canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, width / 2, height / 2);
      return canvas.toDataURL();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

サンプルコード:

```
// 画像データ(DataURL)を縮小して返す
function makeSmall(data) {
  // 画像データの縦横サイズを取得する
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = data;
  var width = image.naturalWidth;
  var height = image.naturalHeight;

  // 縮小する。今回は縦横それぞれ1/2
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = width / 2;
  canvas.height = height / 2;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0, width / 2, height / 2);

  // データURLにして返す。他にバイナリを返す toBlob() メソッドもあります。
  return canvas.toDataURL();
  // JPEG形式のほうが良い圧縮率が得られると思われます。
  // 第2引数は品質レベルで、0.0~1.0の間の数値です。高いほど高品質。
  // return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Android Browser 3, Safari 6, IE10, Chrome 4, Firefox 3.6 以降で動作すると思われます。

Comment: データ形式に関するコメントを追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

mysticateaさん、信用度足りないので解答欄で(

toDataURLはデフォルトだと非圧縮png形式出力なので、容量低減目的であればjpeg出力をおすすめします。

```
var png_img = canvas.toDataURL();
var jpeg_img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
if( png_img.length > jpeg_img.length ){
 /*jpegの方が軽い*/
}else{
 /*pngの方が軽い又はjpeg出力未対応でpng化された等*/
}
```

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。仕様を確認するとデフォルトの圧縮レベルは規定されていないように見えたので、実装依存ぽい。写真であれば、jpegのほうが良い圧縮率が得られそうですね。

Comment: @mysticateaさん、確かにw3c確認しても圧縮率の規定は設定されていなかったですね。申し訳ありません。
前にtoDataURLを弄っていた頃の単なる経験則だったみたいです。